# Não criar pasta ao clonar projeto do Gitlab

Tags: git

Tenho junto com meus parceiros um repositório no Gitlab. O repositório já apresenta por padrão, a pasta `api` e demais `txts`, ou seja, não tenho uma pasta dentro do repositório, onde, abrindo nela, tenho acesso aos arquivos que são alterados.

Porém quando faço `git clone` no repositório, ele sempre cria uma pasta (com o nome do projeto) e joga os arquivos de alteração dentro. Alguém sabe se tem algum comando ou algo assim em que ele não crie essa pasta por padrão?

Comment: só uma duvida, você está falando do primeiro 'git clone' ou seja, ambiente novo? ou está realizando um git clone dentro de um git já clonado? exemplo, "'primeiro' git clone repo.git cd repo" "'segundo git clone dentro de repo' git clone repo.git cd repo 'ver as alterações mais novas" se for, o git clone só se faz uma vez por ambiente, a partir deste é só "git fetch/git remote prune/git pull" se entendi errado, deixa passar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode fazer o git clone com um `.` no final, o `.` substitui o caminho default de onde o projeto vai ser criado.

```
git clone url-projeto .
```

Comment: Show, funcionou aqui vlw!

Answer (score 3):

O comando git clone recebe 2 parâmetros: o endereço do repositório e o caminho onde será feito o clone. Esse 2o parâmetro é opcional e, caso omitido, é criado um diretório com o mesmo nome do repositório.

Ex: `$ git clone https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2 mylibgit`

Documentação: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação e o docs mano!